# Easy to use web-based reporting tool

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence

I'm looking for recommendations for an easy to use reporting/business intelligence tool that can interface with an sql server or access database. It can be web-based or a desktop tool.

Ideally it would be freeware or low cost, and easy to use for users who are not that technically savvy (below the level of someone who can generate reports and complicated queries in Access).

Any tools I've seen so far (such as Crystal Reports) are either too expensive or too complicated to use for non-power users.

Comment: Are you looking for a software that will let that user create their own report or something that will display predefined reports that you created.
Also, do you have a language you would like to use if needed.

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services?

Comment: some new alternatives as for 2018: for end users this might be  SeekTable (this is free cloud BI tool), for embedding into web app PivotData microservice can be used (commercial on-premise product)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the two most well known open source alternatives are:

- [Pentaho Reporting](http://reporting.pentaho.org/)
- [JasperReports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports)

I've been looking at them previously, but honestly haven't tried any of them as my company at the time decided to go for a commercial (expensive) alternative.

Comment: I've used JasperReports and it's not very good. If you're using sql server already, you should take a serious look at reporting services.

Comment: Don't expect reporting services to be compatible with anything else but internet explorer (quirks mode, non-iframe, in intranet only). SSRS doesn't even render properly on the web with IE fin quirksmode (e.g rotate270 rows)

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements are very unspecific. You are searching a simple tool. Do you mean an ad-hoc reporting tool such as **[i-net Clear Reports](https://www.inetsoftware.de/external-services/remote/public/remote/adhoc)**?

Answer (score 2):

[Pentaho reporting](http://reporting.pentaho.org/) (from the Community edition of the [Pentaho BI Suite](http://community.pentaho.com/)) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services Report Builder for SQL is about the simplest.
You do have to provide a model of your data for it but that would be necessary for users who dont understand the data structures anyway (sounds like you have that sort of user).

RS comes free with SQL Server too.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but the one thing you'll find users doing even if you get a reporting tool is that they'll move their data to Excel for final output.

This is one of the reasons why SQL Server's BI tools integrate so nicely with Excel - they did some studies that found users have a tendency to revert to Excel, since everyone knows how to use and and knows how to make Excel output look exactly the way they want it to.

Having said this, you might want to consider some Excel based reporting solutions, or tools that integrate with Excel.

[Palo](http://www.jedox.com/en/home/overview.html), which is free, is similar to Cognos TM1 (spendy!) and will let users create reports in Excel. It also has a very Excel-like web interface.

Comment: Good answer.   Not so sure about the specific recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through [SBOeCube](http://www.sboecube.com), this is a Business Intelligence Reporting Tool for SAP Business One.

Answer (score 0):

will this work for you?
http://www.hkvstore.com/phpreportmaker/

and of course you can always start your own.

Answer (score 0):

If they're that technically unsavvy, you'll also need to make sure the database presents useful entities.  If they have to assemble their own Orders, for instance, they're not likely to be successful no matter how simple the tool is.

I've seen the "you can write your own reports!" thing blow up several times.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to try DBxtra.
[www.dbxtra.com](http://www.dbxtra.com)

Answer (score 0):

QlikView is one of the emerging reporting tool

http://www.qlikview.com/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try Quick Reporting Tool. It is simple and easy to use. The SQL scripts created from its Developer Module can be directly executed by user in the End-User Module without any screen design or programming skill needed.

Online demo:
[Quick Reporting Tool Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=VTRdN9ZJdAY)

WebSite:
[www.little-creations.net](http://www.little-creations.net/)